# Adaptive streaming for AUDIO in HTML5

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, aac, mpeg-dash

I have big collection of CC music, which I want to stream.
I want adaptive streaming for users with low internet connection to not wait every 5 sec for buffering.
I read about mpeg-dash, hls, etc and it seems that mpeg-dash supports only mp4 and ts containers, I am not sure if I can do what I want.

I have LC-AAC-320k and HE-AAC-64k files. Quality matters, and I hear the difference between HE-AAC and LC-AAC-320 even on realtek audio.

Is it possible to do adaptive streaming for these formats with support for Chrome, Firefox, Safari? If not, is there any way to detect low bandwidth (often buffering) and switch to HE-AAC?